# Access/SSH device on different subnet

Tags: ssh

My network setup is as follows:

I have my main gateway router which is what most everyone in the house uses. I have a dedicated router running an openVPN client connected via a LAN port on the main gateway router to the WAN port on the VPN router. Both routers have DHCP enabled.

I normally work from a machine connected to another LAN port on the main gateway router, but I would like to connect to my raspberrypi via SSH that is connected to a LAN port on the VPN router.

Main router's IP address is 192.168.1.1 
VPN router's IP address is 192.168.0.1

My work computer's IP 192.168.1.125 (assigned via DHCP by the main router)

The vpn router's assigned IP address from the main router is 192.168.1.108

The rpi's IP address is 192.168.0.228 (assigned via DHCP by the vpn router)

When I look at the devices IP addresses via the router interface on the main router, I see the raspberrypi listed as being assigned 192.168.1.146.

How can I reach the Raspberry via SSH from my work machine connected to the main router?

Comment: Is your VPN router configured correctly? Did you set up port forwarding? You could just connect the raspberry pi to a screen and keyboard and then check what ip addresses it got with `ifconfig`

Comment: I have had the Raspberrypi connected to a keyboard and monitor but that would defeat the whole purpose. I want to be able to connect it remotely. The VPN router works, the devices connected to it are on the VPN and show the VPN's IP address but I'm just a bit unsure how to set it up to be able to connect to the RPI via SSH from the other router.

Comment: If the VPN router forces all ip packets to go through the VPN connection there is no way to connect to the pi unless the VPN server offers port forwarding. You have to configure the VPN router to to accept incoming connections from the local network.

Comment: I think I can get around the issue of the VPN by simply switching WiFi networks in order to SSH to the Pi.

Comment: First thing to do is download Advanced IP Scanner and tell it to scan both ranges.  If it is visible then you probably can.